# CASTing to a column_type that is only known at runtime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

In MySQL I am retrieving a `column_type` from `information_schema.columns`, and then want to produce a `SELECT` statement that `CASTs` to the `column_type`. However, both `CAST` and `CONVERT` seem to have their own ideas as to what a data type is. For example, I'm often receiving `VARCHAR(64)`, `TEXT`, and `INT(10) UNSIGNED` from the information schema, and want to essentially perform `` CONVERT(`Table`.`Column`, INT(10) UNSIGNED) `` but it says this is a syntax error.

I would need to write it as `` CONVERT(`Table`.`Column`, UNSIGNED) ``, but in that case I'm going to need to write code that parses every possible response for `column_type` and convert it into a `CAST` equivalent, and even then it won't be guaranteed to produce the code I need: What if I'm taking a BIGINT and trying to stuff it into an INT?
Is there any way to perform a cast to the actual column types that are used to define tables?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to `CAST` columns in a `SELECT` to the data type that the columns are stored as?  If so, *why*?

Comment: You can't cast a *table*, only an *expression* (which may simply be a column).

Comment: I'm trying to cast a column to the datatype of a column in another table. Why? Because that's where the data is going. I don't know which column the data is going to until run time. However, I want to make sure that the value is the same before and after and, if not tell me so I can do something intelligent.

Comment: I changed your title a bit, because the problem you're having is that you want to insert the column type *at runtime*.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create an SQL statement by using a value from another SQL statement.

This is called "dynamic SQL" and in MySQL this is only possible by creating a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) inside a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html). Furthermore, a prepared statement can only be created from a [user variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html).

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...() BEGIN
  DECLARE desired_type VARCHAR(255);
  SELECT column_type FROM information_schema.columns ... INTO desired_type;
  SET @your_dynamic_sql = CONCAT("UPDATE ... SET ... = CONVERT(..., ", desired_type, ");");
  PREPARE update_statement FROM @your_dynamic_sql;
  EXECUTE update_statement;
END
```